# How to create FMX.Graphics.TBitmap with specific pixel format?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, pixelformat

Probably I am missing something, but I can't find a way to create FMX bitmap with a specific pixel format. To be more specific, I need to create `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap` with pixel format `BGR_565`. The Constructor doesn't have an option to define PixelFormat. The property `PixelFormat` is readonly (unlike VCL version of `TBitmap`).

Comment: It's not a simple task as it seems. I was hoping for hacking `TBitmap` through `TBitmap.Map` method where I tried to replace the bitmap data record by a new one created with the desired pixel format. No change (Tokyo).

Comment: What if we create VCL bitmap 1x1 `pf16bit`, save it to file, load into FM Bitmap and resize? (same for resourcestream storage)

Comment: @MBo This doesn't work too. When i load 16bit bitmap it is automatically converted to 32bit BGRA. As far as i can see in FMX units, there are always created bitbamp with all default setting and if any pixel processing required, it is done in style pixel-by-pixel. I am starting to suspect that it is not possible at all to create FMX bitmap with pixelformat i need.

Comment: Seems i found how it should work - we can create TBitmapSurface with required PixelFormat (it has PixelFormat as parameter of SetSize function), Then we can call Bitmap.Assign (it supports TBitmapSurface as src). But it doesn't work too, TBitmap.AssignFromSurface is trying to copy source bits with MOVE proc as if it is always 32 bits per pixel (so it will either fail because of access bytes outside of src region or produce garbage in format BGRA).

Comment: Seems FMX in this part is not implemented properly. Will have to try something else (maybe some 3th party lib).

Comment: It seems to be hardcoded now. See e.g. code for Windows, there's used `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` format only.